# Minimize the number of groups but separate the enemies in different groups

Tags: r, algorithm, grouping

I have `n=4` individuals named `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Some individuals can belong to the same group and some can't. This info is given by the following (coded in `R`)

```
comparisons =          c("A-B",   "A-C",  "A-D",   "B-C",    "B-D",  "C-D")
areEnemies =           c(FALSE,   FALSE,   TRUE,   FALSE,    FALSE,   TRUE)
```

From these data, the individuals `A` and `D` are enemies and cannot belong to the same group. The individuals `C` and `D` and enemies cannot belong to the same groups either. All other pairs of individuals are friends (when you someone is not your enemy, then (s)he is your friend).

My goal is to create groups so that

1. The number of groups is minimized
2. An individual can belong to one or more group (but must belong to at least one group)
3. If two individuals are enemies, then they must never be in the same group. If two individuals are friends (not enemies), then they must be in the same group at least once.
4. If an individual can belong to a group, then it must!

The solution (using lower case letters for the group names) for the above example is

- `A` belongs to group `a`
- `B` belongs to group `a` and to group `b`
- `C` belongs to group `a`
- `D` belongs to group `b`

I fail to wrap my head around this problem. Can you provide give me a hand?

---

If you want to write code I welcome R, C, C++, Java, Bash, Python but a verbal description of the process (or pseudo-code) would already be very helpful. Note that performance will not be of much concern as I typically have only 5-10 individuals and won't run this process too often.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If it is it may be nice to have that out there for others to know. :)

Comment: It is not a homework question (I'm doing my PhD in genetics and am not taking any class). I have tried something that failed but there is quite a stretch between the original problem and the simplified version presented here that it will take some time to reformat my failed attempt.

Comment: So *friends* is missing from the above coding? How big are your real-world instances?

Comment: @sasha Any pair of individuals that are not enemies and friends. So all the input data needed are present in the above code. I typically have about 5-10 individuals. Performance is a priori not going to be very important (I am planning to code it in `R`).

Comment: Given *I typically have about 5-10 individuals. Performance is a priori not going to be very important*: just write a brute-force solver. This is then quite basic programming. For performance-critical and bigger instances i would have recommended Integer-programming, Constraint-programming, SAT-solving: the classic discrete-optimization approaches. **Edit** i'm also somewhat sceptic about those rules. What is the purpose of 4? I think it's not formal enough. Maybe there isa case: given a G=3 groups solution will have only 1 grouping for all; while another G=3 solution might have > 1 groupings.

Comment: I had doubt about rule 4 too at the beginning but I think it is needed. If it is not needed, then it is just extra redondant information but should not be misleading. I think there is a single solution to any input but I might be wrong and would love explanations for why I am wrong if it the case. I don't understand what you mean by `Maybe there isa case: given a G=3 groups solution will have only 1 grouping for all; while another G=3 solution might have > 1 groupings`  is `G` the number of individuals (that I call `n`)?

Comment: I just meant: maybe you introduced rule 4 to make groups as large as possible (or something related). But there might be (did not check it) a case, where one solution minimizes criterion A and every n in N is only used in exactly one group. But in the global-space of solutions, there might be a solution with the same criterion A score, where some n in N are grouped more then once. In this case, given my assumption what 4 is used for, it will fail as stated as that (well... depends on how one reads that rule). Maybe such cases do not exist. Brute-forcing will show it.

Comment: Can you give an example that might have 3 groups?

Comment: So can you formalize rule 4 somehow?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number_(graph_theory)

Comment: If you neglect (4) this looks like a question about vertex coloring, so perhaps you can get some hints from e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Exact_algorithms

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is essentially a graph problem

Data

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(A = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
        B = c("B", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D"),
        lgl = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  # A     B     lgl  
  # <chr> <chr> <lgl>
# 1 A     B     F    
# 2 A     C     F    
# 3 A     D     T    
# 4 B     C     F    
# 5 B     D     F    
# 6 C     D     T
```

1 - Filter out enemies from the data frame, 2 - then make an undirected graph (plot it to see it). 3 - determine `max_cliques` of the graph.

```
library(igraph)
data <- filter(df, lgl == FALSE)   # friends
G <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed=FALSE)
plot(G)
max_cliques(G)

# [[1]]
# + 2/4 vertices, named, from 5940a66:
# [1] D B

# [[2]]
# + 3/4 vertices, named, from 5940a66:
# [1] A B C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#checks if two people are enemies 
def areEnimies(a, b, enemies):
    for x in enemies:
        if (x[0] is a and x[1] is b) or (x[1] is a and x[0] is b):
            return True
    return False

enemies = ["AD", "CD"]  #list of enemies side by side
people = "ABCD" #the list of people who are in the game
groups = []
ans = []
#for each unique enemy, give them there own group
for x in enemies:
    if not x[0] in groups:
        groups.append(x[0])
    if not x[1] in groups:
        groups.append(x[1])
#populate this group with everyone else who is not their enemy
for g in range(len(groups)):
    for p in people:
        if not areEnimies((groups[g])[0], p, enemies) and (groups[g])[0] != p:
            groups[g] += p

#sort each group
for g in range(len(groups)):
    groups[g] = sorted(groups[g])

#if any groups are duplicates of one another we can remove them 
for i in range(len(groups)):
    dup = False
    for j in range(i+1, len(groups)):
        if groups[i] == groups[j]:
            dup = True
            break
    if not dup:
        ans.append(groups[i])

print(ans)
```

> output = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'D']]

```
> This is what I came up with
> 1. Write down each unique person that is enemies with someone
> 2. Populate each of those lists with friends 
> 3. Remove duplicate groups if they exist
```

Enemies are given by unordered pairs and the people who are being put in groups are represented in a string, note we do not need a list of friends as anyone who is not an enemy we can assume to be a friend. There are probably more efficient ways to do this but its reasonable for small groups and worked with a couple different inputs I tried

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is essentially a graph theory problem. Here are the steps to go

1. Consider an edge between each friends but not between enemies
2. List all the [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory))
3. Remove all cliques that are included in bigger cliques.
4. Make sure that vertices that have no friend gets a group too

Here is the code in `R`

```
### input data
d <- tibble(A = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
        B = c("B", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D"),
        friend = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))

### list vertices
vertexes = unique(c(d$from,d$to))

## Create graphs of friends
dFriend = d[d$friend,]
gFriend = graph.data.frame(dFriend, directed=FALSE)

## List all cliques
cliques = lapply(cliques(gFriend), function(x) {names(x)})

## Remove cliques that are contained within other cliques
if (length(cliques))
{
  cliqueIndicesToRemove = c()
  for (i in 1:length(cliques))
  {
    clique_sub = cliques[[i]]
    for (j in 1:length(cliques))
    {
      if (i!=j)
      {
        clique_sup = cliques[[j]]
        if (all(clique_sub %in% clique_sup))
        {
          cliqueIndicesToRemove = c(cliqueIndicesToRemove, i)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cliques = cliques[-unique(cliqueIndicesToRemove)]
}

## return object
r = tibble(
  cliques   = "",
  vertex    = vertexes   
  )
if (length(cliques))
{
  for (i in 1:length(cliques))
  {
    clique = cliques[[i]]
    matchingVertexes = which(r$vertex %in% clique)
    for (match in matchingVertexes)
    {
      r$cliques[match] = paste0(r$cliques[match], letters[i]  )
    }
  }
}

## Make sure that vertices with no friend still get assigned to a clique
nextLetterIndex = length(cliques) + 1
for (i in 1:nrow(r))
{
  if (r$cliques[i] == "")
  {
    r$cliques[i] = letters[nextLetterIndex]
    nextLetterIndex = nextLetterIndex + 1 
  }
}
```

This solution was very much inspired from @CPak's answer.